# Dividing Two Sums From Same Level Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I want to sum shares by grouped by ATS_MPID, then also by Trades_Last_Updated, and I want to then divide the two (ATSSum / Trades_Last_UpdatesSum).  This is what I have so far..thank you

```
 WITH symboltotals AS (
 SELECT Symbol, SUM(Shares) AS SymTot, Trades_Last_Updated
    FROM ATS AS S
    GROUP BY Trades_Last_Updated, Symbol),
atstotals AS (
SELECT Symbol, ATS_MPID, SUM(Shares) as "ATSTotal" 
FROM ATS AS A
GROUP BY ATS_MPID, Symbol)

SELECT *
FROM symboltotals, atstotals
WHERE symboltotals.Symbol = atstotals.Symbol
```

Sample Data:

```
Symbol  ATS_MPID    Shares  Trades_Last_Updated
A       BIDS        317800  9/17/2018
A       CROS        125508  9/17/2018
A       BIDS        124300  9/10/2018
A       CROS        117419  9/10/2018
```

I'm trying to Get the percent per ATS_MPID for all shares traded.  So sum Symbol A for BIDS (9/17 & 9/10), do the same for CROS, then divide those totals by the total shares to see their individual contribution %... i.e.:  (Shares of BIDS 9/17 + Shares of BIDS 9/10) / Total Shares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data and your statement of problem, following query will help

```
create table yourtable(Symbol varchar(100),  ATS_MPID varchar(100),    Shares bigint, Trades_Last_Updated datetime);
insert into yourtable values
 ('A',  'BIDS',    317800,  '9/17/2018')
,('A',  'CROS',    125508,  '9/17/2018')
,('A',  'BIDS',    124300,  '9/10/2018')
,('A',  'CROS',    117419,  '9/10/2018');


select *,
    percentage=(sum(shares) over (partition by Symbol, ATS_MPID)*100.00)/sum(shares) over (partition by Symbol)
    --,percentagePerLastUpdated=(sum(shares) over (partition by Symbol, ATS_MPID, Trades_Last_Updated)*100.00)/sum(shares) over (partition by Symbol)
from yourtable
```

also see <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/FNRF49740)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, wow I haven't used that method in a long time, great idea.  I believe its close but I now need to group the data by ATS_MPID (for there are 2 dates under Trades_Last_Updated.  So i'm getting two lines of data for each symbol and ATS_MPID.  How can I group the Share totals by Trades_Last_Updated & ATS_MPID?  Thanks very much

Comment: I added sample data to my question..thank you very much

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  the %'s look correct but how can i avoid getting two rows of data per ATS_MPID as the answer (the %) seems redundant?  I do not need it per date, I need one answer per Symbol, ATS_MPID... thank you!

Comment: Use distinct and in stead of `select *` use `select symbol, ats_mpid`